# DC-DC converter cause PC GPU computer to shut down

Tags: dc-dc-converter, transient, gpu

I am currently trying to power up a edge GPU computer that runs on 12-19 V and is rated for 60 W.

Whenever I start to overclock my computer to run some machine learning stuff, the computer will just shut down. I notice on my bench supply that it draws between 1 A to 2 A as it rapidly swings inbetween this range. I tried a few DC-DC converters as well, from famous brands that are rated 200-300 W, but the computer will just shutdown.

My take is that the transient current change is so rapid that the short circuit protection of the DC supplies kick in.

A thing I noticed was that when I directly use the computer AC adapter plugged into the mains, it's able to work perfectly

May I know:

1. if my assessment is accurate.
2. Would like to understand if it's not accurate.
3. How can I allow my computer to still work without reducing its performance i.e. what can I do in a electrical standpoint to compensate?

My first time posting! Sorry if it sounds amateurish.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question to add new info (putting it into the text rather than headed 'Edit'), rather than in a comment. Otherwise, readers have to piece it all together. You can delete that comment afterwards. Again, welcome.

Comment: Thx @TonyM, edited my question